# Overriding an extending class

Tags: java

So let's say I have class A that does similar things as class B.

I know there are a lot of examples, but they won't work with my method very well.

```
public class B extends A {

    public void doSomething(){..}

    public String toString(){..}//not important

}
```

What should I write to override the doSomething() method in class B?

Comment: If you're overriding a method, then you're stating that class A has that same method, yes?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: What makes you think you need to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

You should just reimplement it. Although not strictly required, I'd also annotate the method with `@Override` to clarify this overrides `A`'s behavior:

```
public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void doSomething(){
        // implementation goes here.
        // may or may not call super.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So let's say I have class A that does similar things as class B.

Then you should simply not create B class as it is not userfull , but since you have created it and want to know how it will get override then first understand what is method overriding

[This Article will help you](http://www.javatpoint.com/method-overriding-in-java) , In short

> If subclass (child class) has the same method as declared in the
>   parent class, it is known as method overriding in java.

So if your class A has method with same signature

`public void doSomething(){..}`

then you are already overriding it ,

Annotating overriding method with 
`@override` will indicate the compiler that this is an overridden method and if i forgot to override it correctly then please tell me by throwing compile time error